# Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime. Error for one date converting only

Tags: c#, .net, umalquracalendar

My code is working fine for all date except one that is 2019,10,28. i do not know why i am getting error to convert this date to umulqura or hijri.

```
        UmAlQuraCalendar HijriCalender = new UmAlQuraCalendar();
        var date = new DateTime (2019,10,28);
        var check = ConvertToHijri(date);

    public static DateTime ConvertToHijri(this DateTime value)
    {
        try
        {
        if (value.Year > 1500)
        {
                GregorianCalendar Gre = new GregorianCalendar();
                UmAlQuraCalendar HijriCalender = new UmAlQuraCalendar();

  DateTime gDate = new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day, Gre);
                var year = HijriCalender.GetYear(gDate);
                var month = HijriCalender.GetMonth(gDate);
                var day = HijriCalender.GetDayOfMonth(gDate);
                var test = new DateTime(year, month, day);
                return test;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return value;
    }
```

this code works very fine to convert dates from Georgian to Hijri or Umulqura but only specific date 2019,10,28 is not converting.

Comment: Might help [Convert From Georgian Date English Date To Arabic Hijri Date Umm Al Qura](http://mohdaoud.blogspot.com/2009/02/convert-from-georgian-date-english-date_2235.html) and [Convert date from Hijri Calendar to Gregorian Calendar and vise versa](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8838/Convert-date-from-Hijri-Calendar-to-Gregorian-Cale) Good luck.

Comment: @JQSOFT as i mentioned in my question i have problem only with one date. My code works perfect except one date only. Thank you.

Comment: That's 29-Safar-1441.  Safar is the 2nd month in the calendar.  Like February in the Georgian calendar.  Which did not have a 29th day in the year 1441, so new DateTime(year, month, day) is going to blow.  You just can't express such calendar dates in DateTime.

Comment: @HansPassant dear there is date of 29th of Safar in all hijri and umulqura calendars. And if we imagine we don't have 29 in safar then converted date should be 1 of Rabi ul Awal the 3rd month of hijri calendar.